# 'BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead' or simply 'BufFilePre,BufRead' when detecting a filetype?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

The following snippet is from the [`vim-pandoc-syntax`](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax) plugin README:

> If you want to use vim-pandoc-syntax without vim-pandoc, you'll need to tell Vim to load it for certain files. Just add something like this to your vimrc:
>
> ```
> augroup pandoc_syntax
>     au! BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown.pandoc
> augroup END
> ```

What might be the reason to use `BufNewFile` here? Isn't it that `BufFilePre` and `BufRead` are sufficient?

When we create a new empty buffer, its `filetype` value is blank in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using `:h ftdetect` is preferred over direct approach. This way you add commands into predefined `filetypedetect` augroup and so you don't need to create yet another one.
2. `BufNewFile` is needed to handle `:e newfile.md` and such. And, no, in this case a newly created file can get a correct filetype even though it has neither contents nor it was read from disk.
3. `BufFilePre` is not useful here. I guess you mean `BufFilePost` instead. But it's only triggered after `:file` or `:saveas` commands, so usually no one cares.

Comment: It seems that in addition to `BufNewFile`, `BufFilePost`, and `BufRead`, there should be `FileChangedShellPost`.

Comment: @johnc.j. There's no need for that.

Comment: I have tested it with `autocmd BufFilePost,BufNewFile,BufReadPost,FileChangedShellPost *.md set syntax=off`. If I change a file to read-only by using the shell, Vim will prompt me to re-load it, and then if I choose to do so, syntax highlighting will be turned on (unless I add `FileChangedShellPost`).

Comment: @johnc.j. As expected, as you have automatic syntax.